# Logging in custom time format

Tags: python, python-2.7

The logging module offers automatic display off information next to the logging message:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s {%(filename)s:%(lineno)s} in %(funcName)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I want to include the seconds from start of the runtime of the script. logging module offers `msecs` but how can i include the seconds since start inside this format string?

Answer (score 1):

In the [documented logrecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):

```
relativeCreated %(relativeCreated)d 

Time in milliseconds when the LogRecord was created, relative to 
the time the logging module was loaded.
```

Comment: I wanted the seconds, not the milliseconds, msecs offers the same functionality.